# Experimental Values for Amplitude $\delta^*$ of Particle Displacement in Acoustic Fields?

Tags: acoustics

I've been searching but have been unable to find any experimental values for the amplitude $\delta^*$ of the particle displacement from equilibrium that particles in a medium such as air will undergo when a sound wave propagates through that medium. This parameter $\delta^*$ shows up a lot in theoretical treatments of sound, such as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_displacement), and sure we can relate it to a bunch of other parameters like amplitude $v^*$ of particle velocity and the temporal angular frequency $\omega$ of the sound wave, but ultimately I would be interested to know if there are any experimentally tabulated values for $\delta^*$ in various different circumstances.

Comment: Duplicate [What is the relationship between pressure and displacement of a sound wave in a tube?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/585422/what-is-the-relationship-between-pressure-and-displacement-of-a-sound-wave-in-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't find it tabulated anywhere
because particle displacement ($\delta^*$) and likewise
particle velocity ($v^*$) and sound pressure ($p^*$)
all depend on the loudness of the sound.

Loudness is often measured in a logarithmic dB (dezibel) scale.
The [sound pressure level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound#Sound_pressure_level) $L_p$ is defined as
$$L_p=20 \log_{10}\left(\frac{p^*}{p^*_\text{ref}}\right) \text{dB}$$
or equivalently
$$p^*=p^*_\text{ref} 10^{L_p/20\text{ dB}}$$
where is $p^*$ is the sound pressure and $p^*_\text{ref}$
is a reference sound pressure (for air it is
$p^*_\text{ref}=2\cdot 10^{-5}$ Pa). For example:

- $L_p=0$ dB (corresponding to $p^*=2\cdot 10^{-5}$ Pa) is so quiet
  that it is hardly perceivable.
- $L_p=130$ dB (corresponding to $p^*=63$ Pa) is so loud that it damages the ear.

With the [relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_displacement) $v^*=\omega\delta^*$ and
$p^*=\rho c\omega\delta^*$
you can then calculate particle displacement $\delta^*$
and particle velocity $v^*$ from the sound pressure $p^*$.

Comment: Good answer with concentrated information. I just wanna make a minor correction here. The term "loudness" is used for the subjective feeling of how "strong" a sound is, which has a weaker connection to pressure (and displacement) amplitude than the sound pressure level (it is also frequency dependent). Additionally, level refers to the logarithmic (in dB) counterpart of a quantity in acoustics. For example Sound Pressure Level is actually pressure converted to a logarithmic (dB) scale, with some reference value always in effect. +1 from me.